# Kolmogorov-Smirnov CDF

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I'm writing some C++ code that uses a two-sample K-S test. I've computed the largest difference between the two cumulative density functions, $D$, and then compute the test statistic $x = \sqrt{\frac{n_1 n_2}{n_1 + n_2}} D$.

Does anyone know of a simple form for the cumulative density function under the null hypothesis? I found the asymptotic form when $n \rightarrow \infty$ on Wikipedia:
[image]

But I haven't been able to find any approximation where $n$ is not large. Can you give me the formula or provide a reference?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You may read how SPSS computes p-value for KS test (one-sample, 2-sample) in this [document](http://mondi.web.elte.hu/spssdoku/algoritmusok/npar_tests.pdf)

Comment: This is expressible in terms of a [Jacobi Theta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html), $\frac{1}{x} e^{\frac{3 \pi ^2}{8 x^2}} \left(e^{-\frac{\pi ^2}{2 x^2}}\right)^{3/4} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \vartheta_2\left(0,e^{-\frac{\pi ^2}{2 x^2}}\right)$.  But what is your question?  It seems to have been cut off after "$n$ i...".